# Do I need a special external hard drive to use with Time Machine

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine

I am searching for a hard drive but I wonder if just about any will allow me to partition it so that I can use a part of it for Time Machine only. Thanks.

Comment: **Sidenote:** If you purchase an EHD to use as a "Time Machine," [it's recommended](http://pondini.org/TM/3.html) to use it only for that purpose. However, if you decide to use the disk for other data as well, partitioning, as you intend to do, is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

No special drive required. It only need support being partitioned as `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` (also known has HFS+) -- which just about any external drive from major manufacturers support. Make sure it supports a physical connection protocol (USB 2, USB 3, FireWire, Thunderbolt, etc.) that your specific Mac happens to have and you're good to go.